# SQL join with table that is missing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, left-join

I have a table that holds information for a given date. I have a second table holding additional information for some dates. Unfortunately the second table does not have information for every date that is in the first table.

Now, I want to be able to join my first table with the information from the second table but whenever the additional information is missing in the second table, I want to join it with the information from the previous date or the date before that, up to a limit of, say, 7 days.

I have no idea on how to solve that without having a subselect with a max() function, which has a very bad performance.

I'll try and illustrate my problem with a quick example:

```sql
create table lookups
(
    date_value date not null,
    additional_information nvarchar(10)
)

create table master
(
    date_value date not null,
    information nvarchar(10)
)

insert into master(date_value, information) 
values (convert(date, '20160101', 112), 'one');

insert into master(date_value, information) 
values (convert(date, '20160102', 112), 'two');

insert into master(date_value, information) 
values (convert(date, '20160104', 112), 'three');

insert into master(date_value, information) 
values (convert(date, '20160112', 112), 'three');

insert into lookups(date_value, additional_information) 
values (convert(date, '20160101', 112), 'plus ONE');

insert into lookups(date_value, additional_information) 
values (convert(date, '20160102', 112), 'plus TWO');
```

Now, to get to the additional information I currently do something along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM master

SELECT *
FROM lookups

SELECT 
    *,
    (SELECT additional_information
     FROM lookups
     WHERE date_value = (SELECT MAX(date_value)
                         FROM lookups
                         WHERE date_value <= master.date_value
                           AND date_value >= dateadd(d, -10, master.date_value))
    )
FROM master
```

and I get

```
date_value information
---------- -----------
2016-01-01 one
2016-01-02 two
2016-01-04 three
2016-01-12 three

(4 row(s) affected)

date_value additional_information
---------- ----------------------
2016-01-01 plus ONE
2016-01-02 plus TWO

date_value information 
---------- ----------- ----------
2016-01-01 one         plus ONE
2016-01-02 two         plus TWO
2016-01-04 three       plus TWO
```

I hope some of you can help me finding a more elegant and more importantly faster solution.

While the example is on SQL Server I am actually looking for a solution that will work on Oracle as well.

Comment: are you just trying to get the last 7 days worth of data from lookup table? couldnt you just do it in the where clause of that is the case? Why would you need max? something like where (TRUNC(SYSDATE - 7) < (date_value))

Comment: no, i try and get the lookup-data as close as possible to the given date from the row in the master table. but i don't want to look back more than 7 days.

Comment: what is the desired output from the above tables.

Comment: the desired output is a row where i have the information from the master table on a given date plus the additional information from the lookup-table from the date closest to the given but within a range of 7 days from it.

ultimately i would love to join my two tables where the lookup-table has no date-gaps (unless they extend 7 days) and the additional information is propagated to the following days up to a limit of 7.

in my example, the last row shows that the additional_information from 2016-01-02 is joined to the information from 2016-01-04.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but if you are just trying to get the last 7 days worth of data from lookups why not just write the below.

```
select * 
from master m 
left outer join lookups l on nvl(m.date_value,'null') =  nvl   (l.date_value,'null')
where  (TRUNC(SYSDATE - 7) <= (l.date_value))
```